# Boost serialize child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I have base class User which is serializable :

```
class User
{
public:
    User();
    std::string GetLogin() const;
    void SetLogin(std::string login);

protected:
    std::string mLogin;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & mLogin;

    }
};
```

This class can be inherited by other class like this :

```
class UserA : public User
{
    UserA();
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<User>(*this);
        ar & mIsSomething;
    }
    bool mIsSomething = true;
}
```

To handle those user i have a "manager" class which contain a User vector :

```
class Manager
{
public:

    bool Add(User user);
    bool Remove(unsigned int index);

private:
    std::vector<User> mUsers;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & mUsers;
    }
};
```

So my manager can be filled with UserA , or UserB (never both at the same time). When i retrieve an element from `Manager` i simply cast it back to the correct child class.
This part is working fine.

But when i want to serialize the `Manager` class obviously Boost don't know which kind of `User` i'm trying to serialize and the extra fields from the child class are not serialized.

What are my solution here ?
Does my design is completly wrong ?
Should i specialize my manager class to something like this ?

```
class Manager
    {
        bool Add(UserA user);
        bool Add(UserB user);
    private:
        std::vector<UserA> mUsersA;
        std::vector<UserB> mUsersB;
}
```

Comment: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/

Comment: I'd suggest making `class Manager` a `template <typename UserType> class Manager`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my manager can be filled with UserA , or UserB (never both at the same time)

No it can't:

```
std::vector<User> mUsers;
```

stores `User` objects by value. See [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

### Thoughts

I'd also suggest templating the Manager on the concrete user type, but seeing how you use an actual type hierarchy, it seems you might be looking to actually use the runtime polymorphism.

Since serializing polymorphic types is somewhat more involved, let me show you a sample.

It also shows how to use e.g. `boost::ptr_vector<>` to manage the objects while storing them dynamically.

**<kbd>[Live<sup>1</sup> on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a55f55256a7acf9a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>

#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/ptr_container/serialize_ptr_vector.hpp>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

class User
{
public:
    User() {};
    virtual ~User() {}
    std::string GetLogin() const;
    void SetLogin(std::string login);

protected:
    std::string mLogin;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {
        ar & mLogin;
    }
};

class UserA : public User
{
  public:
    UserA() {};
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<User>(*this);
        ar & mIsSomething;
    }
    bool mIsSomething = true;
};

class UserB : public User
{
  public:
    UserB() {};
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<User>(*this);
        ar & mIsSomethingElse;
    }
    bool mIsSomethingElse = true;
};

template <typename Tag>
class UserGen : public User
{
  public:
    UserGen() {};
  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<User>(*this);
        ar & mIsGen;
    }
    bool mIsGen = true;
};

struct GenA;
struct GenB;
struct GenC;

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(User)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(UserA)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(UserB)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(UserGen<GenA>)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(UserGen<GenB>)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(UserGen<GenC>)

#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

class Manager
{
public:

    template <typename User>
    bool Add(User const& user) {
        mUsers.push_back(new User(user));
        return true; // FIXME?
    }
    bool Remove(unsigned int index) {
        if (mUsers.size() > index) {
            mUsers.erase(mUsers.begin()+index);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void dump() const {
        for (auto& u : mUsers) {
            std::cout << "user of type " << boost::typeindex::type_id_runtime(u) << "\n";
        }
    }

private:
    boost::ptr_vector<User> mUsers;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/)
    {
        ar & mUsers;
    }
};

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        Manager man;
        man.Add(UserA{});
        man.Add(UserB{});
        man.Add(UserGen<GenA>{});
        man.Add(UserGen<GenB>{});
        man.Add(UserGen<GenC>{});

        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa << man;
    }

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);
        Manager man;
        ia >> man;

        man.dump();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
user of type UserA
user of type UserB
user of type UserGen<GenA>
user of type UserGen<GenB>
user of type UserGen<GenC>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> linking boost 1.59 is somehow failing there :(
Thanks @m.s. for figuring out 1.58 still works

Comment: Watch what I did in the [recorded live session](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/demo-boost-serializing-polymorphic-ptr_vector/) (lots of time wasted trying to het the sample to link on Coliru...) ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the use of ptr_vector is mandatory here ? I'd rather avoid pointer if i can (personal preference).I guess i should also add a delete somewhere on all the pointers right ? Sorry if the questions look dumb , i'm mostly using java.

Comment: You **should** avoid pointers, which is why you should use `ptr_vector` over e.g. `std::vector<User*>` :) Look at the documentation for `ptr_vector<>` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html#motivation

Comment: I read the doc of ptr_vector ;) But i was using an std::vector<User> and not a std::vector<User*>. Does it change anything ?. I can't see your recorded session , i got a error 400 from their player :(

Comment: ***YES***. Did you read my answer at all? You **can** use a vector, but then there's really nothing that make it "a child class" (ie. derived class) in any way for all intents and purposes.